# Smooth varieties and dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In the book *Algebraic Geometry II* by Mumford and Oda ([its draft here](https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/AGII.pdf)), I came across the following proposition in the section on smoothness:

> **Proposition 5.3.10** (page 171 in draft)**.** If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a smooth morphism (of schemes) at $x\in X$ of relative dimension $n$ and $y=f(x)$, then $\operatorname{gr}\mathcal O_x$ is a polynomial ring with $n$ variables over $\operatorname{gr}(\mathcal O_y)\otimes_{\mathbb k(y)}\mathbb k(x)$ — more precisely, $\exists t_1,\dotsc,t_n\in\mathfrak m_x/\mathfrak m_x^2$ such that
> \begin{equation}
>   \mathfrak m_x^\nu/\mathfrak m_x^{\nu+1}\cong
>   \bigoplus_{l=0}^{\nu}\bigoplus_{\substack{\text{multi-indices}\\ \alpha,\, \lvert\alpha\rvert=\nu-l}}\bigl(\mathfrak m_y^l/\mathfrak m_y^{l+1}\otimes_{\mathbb k(y)}\mathbb k(x)\bigr)\cdot t^\alpha.
>   \end{equation}
> Thus
> \begin{equation}
>   \mathbf{TC}_{X,x}\cong\mathbf{TC}_{Y,y}\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb k(y)}\mathbb A^n_{\mathbb k(x)}.
>   \end{equation}
> (Here $\mathbf{TC}$ denotes the tangent cone.)

After that, a corollary:

> **Corollary 5.3.15.** If a $K$-variety $X$ is smooth of relative dimension $n$ over $K$ at some point $x\in X$, then $\dim X=n$.
>
> *Proof.* Apply Proposition 5.3.10 to the generic point $\eta\in X$.

I do not understand how the proposition implies the corollary.
Applying the proposition to the generic point $\eta$, it follows that $\operatorname{gr}\mathcal O_\eta=\operatorname{gr}\mathbf R(X)=\mathbf R(X)$, the function field, is a polynomial ring with $n$ variables over $\operatorname{gr}(K)\otimes_K\mathbf R(X)=\mathbf R(X)$.
Then since $\mathbf R(X)$ is a field, $n$ must be $0$.
What is wrong with my argument?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your argument looks fine to me. It seems there is a condition missing in the first proposition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will read carefully the proof of the proposition.

Comment: In the proof of the proposition, the case $X=Y\times\mathbb A^n$ and $f=p_1$ (the projection) is the first proven by induction on $n$, but I found this induction is not working.